# Adding values in tens or five python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

This is a pretty simple thing to do but I just don't know how to do it in python.
basically. if i type in

```
for i  in range (20):
    print (i)
```

it prints out `1,2,3,4,5,6,7....20`

but what i want is for i to come as `5,10,15,20`

Comment: This is explained in the documentation itself. Please check that.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `step` argument of `range` (start at 5, until 21, so 20, and increase by 5 at each step):

```
for i in range (5, 21, 5):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> for i in range(5, 25, 5):
...     print i
...
5
10
15
20
>>> for i in xrange(5, 25, 5):
...     print i
...
5
10
15
20
```

Just add the third parameter of range or xrange which means slice step will be work.